# trying to pass long array between two activities in android

Tags: java, android, long-integer

I am tryig to pass a longArray between two activities through bundle. I have a longArray named "sensIds", but when i pass this array in bundle.pulongArray, its giving an error "The method putLongArray(String, long[]) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, Long[])".
here is my code:

```
 Long[] sens_ids = new Long[getSym.length];  
        for (int i = 0; i < getSym.length; i++) {  
          sens_checked_ids[i] = Long.valueOf(getSym[i]);  
        }  
        Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
       mybundle.putLongArray("sens ids", sens_ids);
       Intent final_intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,FinalActivity.class);
                final_intent.putExtras(mybundle);
                startActivity(final_intent);
```

Can anyone tell what am i doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: The Long and the long seems to be the error. type Your array with lower case long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument type is different in this line ( mybundle.putLongArray("sens ids", sens_ids) ) it is expecting primitive data type but you are passing Wrapper class

```
long[] sens_ids = new long[getSym.length];  
        for (int i = 0; i < getSym.length; i++) {  
          sens_checked_ids[i] = Long.valueOf(getSym[i]);  
        }  
        Bundle mybundle = new Bundle();
       mybundle.putLongArray("sens ids", sens_ids);
       Intent final_intent = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,FinalActivity.class);
                final_intent.putExtras(mybundle);
                startActivity(final_intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

From **Google docs**:

> Long is the wrapper for the primitive type long.

Hence try using the primitive rather. Hope this helps.